# Python Newbie MIT 6.00 raw_input syntax error

Tags: python, raw-input

I've finally got enough motivation to see through the MIT's Opencourse Intro to Computer Science & Programming, Fall 2008. I'm doing this online watching video lectures. Lecture #3 consists of Problem Set #0: Printing Your Name.

I can't believe it, but I'm really stuck on the first line of the first problem.

I need to create a program to ask my last name. So I checked out some online ref. and came to this code:

```
print raw_input('What is your lastname?')
```

However, that was giving a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.
So I read up a bit more and found out that it's probably because I'm using Python 3.2.2. And that I'm to replace the **raw_input()** to just **input()**. However, same `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` remains.

Does anyone have enough patience to help? :)

Comment: Your code is still in python 2, in python 3 `print` is a function, so you need parantheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in python 3.x you use function print() not the keyword print.

Comment: Thanks Mouseroot. Here is my complete code:

    print (input('What is your last name?'))
    l = input('What is your last name?')
    print (input('What is your first name?'))
    f = input('What is your first name?')
    print('Your name is ' +f+' '+l)

Comment: Which upon some more tinkering was made even smaller:

    l = input('What is your last name?')
    f = input('What is your first name?')
    print('Your name is ' +f+' '+l)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have got the answer from Lev.

However, I want to add that if you are planning to use python 3 or advanced for this particular course; in such case you "might" find yourself in some difficulty. Because some of the skeleton codes that MIT provides are targeted for python 2.5 + versions. I myself had to change a few code because I was using 2.7.6 (and it was not trivial).

However, please note that this is my view based on my experiences with the two OCW version of introduction to programming (6.00 and 6.00SC). I my knowledge the edX version of the course is basically extremely similar.

Finally, please do not lose hope. It takes time to complete the course, but once you solve one problem MIT makes sure that you really have got a huge boost in your self-confidence. Best of luck.

I hope this will help you.